# Creating new record in Sequel via Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I have following model:

```
DB.create_table :teams do  
  primary_key :id
  column :name, :text, :unique=>true
end

DB.create_table :players do  
  primary_key :id
  column :name, :text, :unique=>true
  column :position, :text
  foreign_key :team_id
end

class Team < Sequel::Model
    plugin :json_serializer
    one_to_many :players
end

class Player < Sequel::Model
    plugin :serialization, :json
    many_to_one :teams
end
```

My full code looks like

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'
require 'sinatra'
require 'db' #model file
require 'thread'
require 'json'
require "sinatra/reloader" if development?  # reload

before do
  @teams = Team.all
end

get '/teams/:id' do |id|
  @team = Team[id]
  haml :team_view
end

post '/teams/?' do 
    Team.create(:name => 'FC Barcelona') 
#here: Read error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for [:name, "FC Barcelona"]:Array>

end
```

Am I thinking wrong? how to do it correctly? 
Can you provide me some working example? 
How I can process JSON data which I want to post?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure what JSON has to do with your question/problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling save inside a Model.new block.  Instead, use create instead of new (create also takes a optional block).

Answer (score 2):

Your first creation doesn't work as written because you have no variable named "name". Perhaps you meant `b.name = jdata`?

It works for me with a valid name attribute, and the call to `create` works fine as well:

```
require 'sequel'
p Sequel::VERSION #=> "3.15.0"

DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table :teams do  
  primary_key :id
  column :name, :text, :unique=>true
end

DB.create_table :players do  
  primary_key :id
  column :name, :text, :unique=>true
  column :position, :text
  foreign_key :team_id
end

class Team < Sequel::Model
  plugin :json_serializer
  one_to_many :players
end

class Player < Sequel::Model
  plugin :serialization, :json
  many_to_one :teams
end

begin
  Team.new do |b|
    b.name = name
    b.save
  end
rescue Exception=>e
  p e
  #=> #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object>
end

Team.new do |b|
  b.name = "Boo!"
  b.save
end
Team.create(:name => 'FC Barcelona')

p Team.all
# [
#  #<Team @values={:id=>1, :name=>"Boo!"}>,
#  #<Team @values={:id=>2, :name=>"FC Barcelona"}>
# ]
```

You'll need to share more details for us to reproduce your problem before we can help. Also note that your code includes some red herrings, which I've included above just for completeness. The Player table, model, relationships, and JSON serialization all do not affect my test case. The code could just as well be:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table :teams do  
  primary_key :id
  column :name, :text, :unique=>true
end
class Team < Sequel::Model; end
Team.create(:name => 'FC Barcelona')
p Team.all
```